# IE7 input positioning bug (sticky!)

Tags: css, internet-explorer, layout

check this page out: http://jsbin.com/itufix with IE (page automatically enables IE7 mode).

Here you'll find examples how inline elements (input and span) are rendered as with display block. All elements margins and padding is set to 0.
If you use Developer tools for IE (IE8-9) you could have noticed that input shows offset: 1.

Can anyone explain what is actually happening and how to fix this?

NOTES

1. Adding float to input fix this, but this is not an option. I need to get this done without float.
2. Input/span and its div parents property hasLayout value is true!
3. Any info related to this bug is welcome.

UPDATE:
Here are more examples of how styles are used: http://jsbin.com/itufix/13. Each field can have description under it, plus the whole div.form-item may float (in case I need more than one field in line)

Comment: Just by looking at that example I can see the internal padding on the input is smaller than the padding of the span. This might account for the slight offset.

Comment: What is this "internal padding" and how do you measure it?

Comment: i started up putting every input into a div and set all input properties to zero, transparent, etc... except the font. and all the properties are set by the container div. so you will never have any problems crossbrowser with some strange paddings or margins, backgrounds or whatever

Comment: Have you ever measured container height? Was it important to you? For me it is: every pixel counts. Please provide the demonstration which works correctly in IE (don't hesitate to use my test page as a background) and I will find what makes difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't float the `input` (why?) then you could do this:

```
*+html input {
    margin-top: -1px;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
}
```

http://jsbin.com/itufix/5

That's using [a CSS hack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_filter#Star_plus_hack) so the workaround is only applied in IE7.

Comment: More about input. Actual structure is <div><label><input>[Extra elements]</div> and it has two modes: 1. non-floating DIV content (uses full width); 2. Floating DIV content.

Comment: This is acceptable hack, thanks. Though it has a drawback: input top/ bottom margins must be set with caution as it would brake IE style.

Comment: True, but it's not particularly difficult to mitigate. Here's an example with `margin: 5px 0`: http://jsbin.com/uwimok/edit#html,live. If you could show me a demo of your "actual structure", I might be able to find a nicer method of making it look the same between other browsers and IE7.

Comment: You see, that is the problem. This should be a basic style, which can be overridden. I don't want to thing about IE hacks every time I want to customize input field. In other words if after a half year I'll change margin to 5px - I want it to be 5px in IE7 too.

Comment: Like I said in my last comment: "If you could show me a demo of your "actual structure", I might be able to find a nicer method of making it look the same between other browsers and IE7.". Show me an example of: "1. non-floating DIV content (uses full width); 2. Floating DIV content.".

Comment: In that demo, adding `float: left` to `input` doesn't cause any problems that I can see: http://jsbin.com/itufix/14. Let's assume there are only two ways to fix this, `margin: -1px 0` and `float: left`. You're not happy with (manually) offsetting the margins, so the only remaining alternative is finding a way to give the `input`s `float: left`. So, what's stopping you from applying `float: left` to your `input`s? Show me a demo of that.

Comment: A lot of problems arise when floats are used in IE7, so if possible I tend to avoid it. However, it is still more practical to use float instead of custom margins in this case. I was trying to find out the reason why this bug is caused and maybe a better fix.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your CSS, I see the following:

```
div.form-item{
    padding: 0 1px;
}
```

Changing this to `padding:0;` seems to remove all padding on the form fields to my eyes. See:

http://jsbin.com/ojeros/2/

Or am I missing something?

Comment: You're missing the fact that this bug happens in IE7.

Comment: I couldn't replicate this. Using JSBin it looked the same in IE7/8/9 but I could have missed it.